# Continue executing method once event occurs in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I am developing a windows forms application that acts in a very similar fashion to a console. The functionality I am trying to implement should work in the same way as `Console.ReadLine()`, with a windows forms button in place of the user pressing the enter key. In the form, there is text box that displays the output text, and a text box that the user can input information to (shown in image).

Edit: What I would like to do is have the application get information from the input text box, then assign that information to a variable within the `Start()` function when the 'enter' button is pressed. The problem I am facing is doing this multiple times for the same function without it proceeding further in the function (i.e. displaying incorrect information in the output text box).

[image: image of windows forms]

It's my understanding that I would need to use the click event from the 'enter' button, but not sure have to "pause" the function until the enter button is clicked.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TextTop_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Enter_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBottom.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        start();
    }

    public void textBoxInput(string message)
    {
        textTop.Text = message;
    }

    public void start()
    {
        textBottom.Text = "Enter name:";

        //need to wait here until enter button is clicked.

        string name = textTop.Text;//get input from top text box

        textBottom.Text = "Enter description:";

        //need to wait here until enter button is clicked again.

        string description = textTop.Text; //get input from top text box
    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking..

Comment: You can't write code for this the same way as in a console app. This is event-driven, so the "wait" is what happens by default when no one is pressing any buttons. It's a totally different way of thinking about how it flows. Don't think of the application as running from the point where you call `start`. Think of it as individual methods that are called when buttons are pressed.

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/windows-forms-overview) might help. "When a user does something to your form or one of its controls, the action generates an event. Your application reacts to these events by using code, and processes the events *when they occur*." So instead of saying in code, "wait for the button to be clicked," we create event handlers that say, "do this when the button is clicked." Waiting is the default behavior.

Comment: Thanks for commenting @AviMeltser, I have amended my question, hope it is more clear now.

Comment: @ScottHannen Thanks as well for the help. That makes it a lot clearer now, and I should be able to change my application to suit, just means a few more functions. For arguments sake, is their a way of waiting in the function using events, despite this going against the nature of windows forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you are trying to simulate a console line application which executes in a sequential manner. As others have noted, Windows Forms don't work sequentially. Events are triggered instead.

I believe what you need to do is keep the state of your operations internally. Have a set of variables with form scope for this purpose:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public const int STEP_INITIAL = 0;
    public const int STEP_GET_NAME = 1;
    public const int STEP_GET_DESCRIPTION = 2;
    public const int STEP_INFO_GATHERED = 3;

    private int _step = STEP_INITIAL;
    private string _name;
    private string _description;

}
```

Your `Start` method can then check on the current state and do what it needs to do:

```
public void start()
{
    switch (_step)
    {
        case STEP_INITIAL:
            textBottom.Text = "Enter name:";                    
            _step = STEP_GET_NAME;
            break;
        case STEP_GET_NAME:
            _name = textTop.Text;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_name))
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid name!");
            else
            {
                textBottom.Text = "Enter description:";
                textTop.Clear();
                _step = STEP_GET_DESCRIPTION;
            }
            break;
        case STEP_GET_DESCRIPTION:
            _description = textTop.Text;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_description))
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid description!");
            else
            {
                //This is your final state, where they have entered all the information
                _step = STEP_INFO_GATHERED;
            }
            break;
    }                       
}
```

There are [obviously] more elegant ways of doing this but this should point you in the right direction. Please check the syntax, I did this off the top of my head.

Lastly, this would be a lot easier if you just had two textboxes for name and description... :-)

Comment: I ended up using an event driven layout, however this answers my original question perfectly, thank-you for your help. It would've been exactly what I needed. +1